# how to attach bitmap file to email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, bitmap, attachment

I have bitmap in my code and i need to send it by email as attachment.
I saved it as file and make send intent but every time i have error (file not found).
this is my code.

save file :

```
private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out;
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);

        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
        if (b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out) == true) {
            Toast.makeText(act,"file created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(act,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

send email :

```
public void sendmail (String filename){
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(path,filename+".JPEG");
        Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"send quotation"));
}
```

Comment: You are not trying to attach a bitmap file but a jpg file.

Comment: When do you have that file not found error? And by whom?

Comment: You are saving the file to internal memory of your app. And telling the email app that it is in external memory. Completely different parhs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all doing

```
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
    if (b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out) == true) {
```

you are calling twice `b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);`

You should do something like `boolean success = b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
if(success){
   // Your code
}`

Said that, are you targetting `Android N` or higher version? If yes, you probably need to `grant uri permissions`

See [File providers and grant permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)  from official documentation